# mysql store +90 digits number starting with zero

Tags: mysql, database, numbers

I need to store a number with +90 digits in my mysqldatabase.

I can't figure out what type of the table should be, and if some other attributes should be applied.

An example number: 00004219087128907490128309172409712089378174801278903710874y8012780731

It is important, that the leading zeros remain in the database.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Create column with datatype `VARCHAR(150)`. It will resolve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your column datatype as `varchar(100)`

Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used

Comment: thx for the reply. It still doesn't store the zeroes. I just tried with the number 000011, and the table only displays 11. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `varchar(90)` as a type for that field.

Example of table definition (for MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  my_big_number varchar(90)
);
```

Comment: thx for your answer. Its the same problem as above. It doesn't display the zeroes

Answer (score 0):

You need a `varchar` datatype to store the lengthy *numeric - string*.

But you should know that it the SQL statement needs to follow *string* specific syntax. That is, surround any value, either numeric, date, or others in single quotes. **`'num or date here'`**. So that the value is treated as a *string*.

In your case, you seem to input `000011` number as is without quotes. And hence MySQL implicitly interpreted it as a number and removed leading zeros.

```
mysql> select 000011, '000011';
+--------+--------+
| 000011 | 000011 |
+--------+--------+
|     11 | 000011 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following `INSERT` example should also help you.

```
mysql> insert into vc_num( vn ) values (000011), ( '000011' );
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from vc_num;
+--------+
| vn     |
+--------+
| 11     |
| 000011 |
+--------+
```